# android video mp4 upload to php server

Tags: java, php, android

hello i am having trouble uploading a video file to my server the code i am using was working before now it no longer works after i switched servers i don't know what the problem is please help 
upload code :

```
private class sendvid extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES), "reelyChat/vids/"+vid_name);
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        File mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + vid_name);


        String url = urls[0];
        uploadvid(url, mediaStorageDir);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        newVideo = mediaStorageDir;
        uploadIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

public int uploadvid(String SERVER_URL, File sourceFileUri){
    int serverResponseCode = 200;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "------------------------afb19f4aeefb356c";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = sourceFileUri;

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
        return 0;  //RETURN #1
    }
    else{
        try{
            Log.v("joshtag","UPLOADING .WAV FILE");
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
            Log.v("joshtag","UL URL: "+url.toString());

            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy            
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            // conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("file", sourceFile.getName());

            conn.setRequestProperty("user", "value_1");

            //so on and so forth...
            //conn.setRequestProperty("param", "value");
            conn.setRequestProperty("connection", "close");
            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";filename=\"" + sourceFile.getName() + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while(bytesRead > 0){
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                Log.i("joshtag","->");
            }
            Log.i("joshtag","->->");
            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
            conn.connect();
            Log.i("joshtag","->->->");
            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.i("joshtag","->->->->");
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage().toString();

            Log.i("joshtag","->->->->->");
            Log.i("joshtag", "HTTP Response is : "  + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            // ------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
            BufferedReader inStream;
            String str="";
            String response="";
            try{
                Log.i("joshtag","->->->->->->");
                inStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

                while((str = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.e("joshtag", "SOF Server Response" + str);
                    response = str;
                }
                inStream.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ioex) {
                Log.e("joshtag", "SOF error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
            }


            conn.disconnect();



            conn = null;
            //close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

            if(serverResponseCode == 201){
               Log.e("*** SERVER RESPONSE: 201" + response);
            }//END IF Response code 201
            // conn.disconnect();
        }//END TRY - FILE READ
        catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("joshtag", "UL error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } //CATCH - URL Exception

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return serverResponseCode; //after try
    }//END ELSE, if file exists.
}
```

php counterpart:

```
$vid_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$split = strtok($vid_name, "_");
$split = strtok("_");
$user = $split;

$target_dir = "../users/$user/profileVid/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
```

here is the logcast:

```
07-14 04:26:47.822 24150-24170/com.reelychat.reelychat I/dalvikvm: "AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=11 RUNNABLE
07-14 04:26:47.822 24150-24170/com.reelychat.reelychat I/dalvikvm:   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41e9d360 self=0x5012c6d0
07-14 04:26:47.822 24150-24170/com.reelychat.reelychat I/dalvikvm:   | sysTid=24170 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1074255192
07-14 04:26:47.822 24150-24170/com.reelychat.reelychat I/dalvikvm:   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=27 stm=17 core=1
07-14 04:26:47.822 24150-24170/com.reelychat.reelychat I/dalvikvm:     at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.expand(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:~91)
07-14 04:26:47.822 24150-24170/com.reelychat.reelychat I/dalvikvm:     at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:201)
07-14 04:26:47.822 24150-24170/com.reelychat.reelychat I/dalvikvm:     at libcore.net.http.RetryableOutputStream.write(RetryableOutputStream.java:61)
07-14 04:26:47.822 24150-24170/com.reelychat.reelychat I/dalvikvm:     at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:98)
07-14 04:26:47.832 24150-24170/com.reelychat.reelychat I/dalvikvm:     at com.reelychat.reelychat.ProfileUser.uploadvid(ProfileUser.java:1027)
07-14 04:26:47.832 24150-24170/com.reelychat.reelychat I/dalvikvm:     at com.reelychat.reelychat.ProfileUser$sendvid.doInBackground(ProfileUser.java:1370)
07-14 04:26:47.832 24150-24170/com.reelychat.reelychat I/dalvikvm:     at com.reelychat.reelychat.ProfileUser$sendvid.doInBackground(ProfileUser.java:1357)
07-14 04:26:47.832 24150-24170/com.reelychat.reelychat I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-14 04:26:47.842 24150-24170/com.reelychat.reelychat I/dalvikvm:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
07-14 04:26:47.842 24150-24170/com.reelychat.reelychat I/dalvikvm:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-14 04:26:47.842 24150-24170/com.reelychat.reelychat I/dalvikvm:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-14 04:26:47.842 24150-24170/com.reelychat.reelychat I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-14 04:26:47.842 24150-24170/com.reelychat.reelychat W/dalvikvm: threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41533930)

07-14 04:26:47.842 24150-24170/com.reelychat.reelychat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.expand(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:91)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:201)
at libcore.net.http.RetryableOutputStream.write(RetryableOutputStream.java:61)
at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:98)
at com.reelychat.reelychat.ProfileUser.uploadvid(ProfileUser.java:1027)
at com.reelychat.reelychat.ProfileUser$sendvid.doInBackground(ProfileUser.java:1370)
at com.reelychat.reelychat.ProfileUser$sendvid.doInBackground(ProfileUser.java:1357)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: what is the server's response? Could be max_upload_size exceeded or something.

Comment: what is the size of the video that you are uploading ?. Also try uploading a video of smaller size and check if that works.

Comment: i dont think its the max_file_upload i have already set it to 500m video file is about 1.6mb

Comment: have u tried uploading a different video ?

Comment: yes the video is recorded each time i want to upload

Comment: As you can see in the log, u r receiving OutOfMemoryError. Clearly there is something which the app cannot handle it. You can increase the heapsize in manifestfile.xml but I wont recommend you doing that. Find the root cause

Comment: Also, it will be helpful if you could share the code from where you are calling  the uploadvid() func

Comment: I recommend you to look at this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977605/how-to-post-large-video-on-a-server-in-android

Comment: i just added the function i use to call the video upload